# Run code after a jQuery UI draggable is cloned using helper:'clone'

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to execute some code on the newly cloned item in draggable. Once the draggable is cloned, I want to use Twitter Bootstrap's popover on an element inside of it.

How can I achieve this while using the following draggable:

```
  $( "#draggables li" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
```

The item being dragged:

```
<ul id="draggables">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="btn pop-me" data-content="popover text">click</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
</ul>
```

In my document load, I call pop over:

```
$('.pop-me').popover()
```

The pop over needs to be called again when the element is cloned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to be sure about what you are expecting, but you can do what you want in the callbacks

```
 $( "#draggables li" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: function(event,ui){
        //Call your function here based on ui or event object
        return $(this).clone();
    },
    stop: function(event,ui){
        //Call your function here based on ui or event object
    }
  });
```

Comment: Great answer, but +1 for "Not sure to be sure" alone... :)